# Obtaining 3 days ago in Elixir using NaiveDateTime

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In RailsLand you can leverage methods that allow you to say things like this `Time.now - 1.day` or `3.days.ago`. For test setup and such these were really nice features of the Rails framework. Does anybody know how to do this with Elixir and Phoenix? I would imagine there is a way but I've had no luck finding anything yet.

I can obviously set the current time like this:

```
NaiveDateTime.utc_now()
```

But how can I set it to three days ago from now? or three days from now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this task you can either use [NaiveDateTime.add/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#add/3) method and add a negative amount of seconds (`259200` for `3` days):

```
NaiveDateTime.utc_now() |> NaiveDateTime.add(-60 * 60 * 24 * 3)
```

Or [`timex`](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) package:

```
use Timex
Timex.now |> Timex.shift(days: -3)
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I'll likely pull that into a helper function so I don't have to type that out everytime.

Answer (score 0):

For the typical use case of querying database there is:

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#module-intervals

which allows somewhat Rails-like constructions. `3.days.ago` becomes `ago(3, "day")` for example.